# cardano-db-sync How could we define an asset as NFT?

Tags: cardano-db-sync

Could anyone tell me if is there any way to check if an asset is NFT using the database of cardano-db-sync?

I tried to look at tx_metadata table and check if in json field contains an image, but many NFTs do not have an image.

I also tried considering an asset as NFT if the mint quantity of them is equal to 1, but it seems that some NFT could be minted more than once and burn as well

Thank you